# What characters does the default analyzer parse on?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to find documentation on how the string analyzers work and more specifically what characters they parse on when building up the terms array for the index?

I have looked [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-text-analysis-part-1) and [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html) without any luck.

Here is an example:

If I were to index a document that had a field called `email` with the value `"test@hotmail.com"` then a match query would return this document if `"test"` or `"hotmail.com"` were given as a query. This shows that the analyzer parses on `@` characters but not on `.` characters.

I would like to know more about what other characters are treated as normal characters, what ones are stripped out altogether, and what ones are parsed on?

Does anyone have an idea where I can find this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in your second link, the default analyzer that kicks in when analyzing your strings is the [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html), which uses the [standard tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-tokenizer.html).

If you check that last link, you'll see that the standard tokenizer enforces the tokenization rules of the [Unicode Standard Annex #29](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/).

In that document, there's a section called [4 Word Boundaries](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Word_Boundaries) and another called [5 Sentence Boundaries](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Sentence_Boundaries) which define exactly how which character and when to split tokens according this various rules and depending on many different Unicode sequences (also depends on which language is being analyzed).

For instance, the period `.` character is only considered as a sentence boundary if it is directly followed by a space (which is not the case in emails).